# Add View between Status Bar and Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiwindow, uistatusbar

What is the proper way to add a view between the Status Bar and the Navigation Bar? I'm trying to create a banner similar to the in-call status bar banner that's present when you're making a call. Right now, I'm simply resizing the window and adding my banner view to the window. It works alright but does not work with transitions.

As you can see below, there is sometimes an overlap. The interesting thing is that the overlap can be resolved by displaying and then hiding the in-call status bar banner. This makes me think this has something to do with the timing of when iOS calculates the window height and/or the application frame.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Screenshot]